# How to change a settimeout into a function instead of a string

Tags: javascript

Here are lines 38-41 of my code for a snake game on JS> I am using JsFiddle

```
createSnake();
locateApple();
setTimeout("gameCycle()", DELAY)
```

The  setTimeout has the error: Implied eval consider passing a function instead of a string.

How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: `setTimeout(gameCycle, DELAY)`

Comment: `setTimeout(gameCycle, DELAY)` use this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

The `setTimeout()` accepts `function` or `code` as first parameter. Using `code` is **not** **recommended**. Use `function` like below,

```
function gameCycle() {}

setTimeout(gameCycle, 3000); // if your delay is 3s

// OR

setTimeout(function() {}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this: `setTimeout(gameCycle, DELAY)`